# Odoo14: How to check if a phone number already exist (Singup page)

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Im trying to add a phone number field in signup page (odo14), the value is saved on DB everything at here is Ok, but when i want to check is a phone number is already exist im getting invalide filed 'db' on 'res.users'

```
if request.env["res.users"].sudo().search([("phone", "=", qcontext.get("phone"))]):
     qcontext["error"] = _("Phone Number Already exist !")
```

Bellow is my controllor code:

```
class AuthSignupHome(AuthSignupHome):
    def do_signup(self, qcontext):
        """ Shared helper that creates a res.partner out of a token """
        qcontext = self.get_auth_signup_qcontext()
```

```
   ** the problem is here: ** ☻
    values = {key: qcontext.get(key) for key in ('db','login', 'name', 'password', 'phone')}
    if not values:
        raise UserError(_("The form was not properly filled in."))
    if values.get('password') != qcontext.get('confirm_password'):
        raise UserError(_("Passwords do not match; please retype them."))

    supported_lang_codes = [code for code, _ in request.env['res.lang'].get_installed()]
    lang = request.context.get('lang', '').split('_')[0]
    if lang in supported_lang_codes:
        values['lang'] = lang
    request.env.cr.commit()
    #override singup_with_values
    super(AuthSignupHome, self._signup_with_values(qcontext.get('token'), values))

 def _signup_with_values(self,token, values):
     db, login, password ,phone = request.env['res.users'].sudo().signup(values,token)
     print("Database name",db)
     request.env.cr.commit()     # as authenticate will use its own cursor we need to commit the current transaction
     uid = request.session.authenticate(db, login, password,phone)
     if not uid:
         raise SignupError(_('Authentication Failed.'))
```

```
@http.route('/web/signup', type='http', auth='public', website=True, sitemap=False)
    def web_auth_signup(self, *args, **kw):
        qcontext = self.get_auth_signup_qcontext()
        if not qcontext.get('token') and not qcontext.get('signup_enabled'):
            raise werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound()

        if 'error' not in qcontext and request.httprequest.method == 'POST':
            try:
                self.do_signup(qcontext)
                # Send an account creation confirmation email
                if qcontext.get('token'):
                    user_sudo = request.env['res.users'].sudo().search([('login', '=', qcontext.get('login'))])
                    template = request.env.ref('auth_signup.mail_template_user_signup_account_created',
                                               raise_if_not_found=False)

                    if user_sudo and template:
                        template.sudo().with_context(
                            lang=user_sudo.lang,
                            auth_login=werkzeug.url_encode({'auth_login': user_sudo.email}),
                        ).send_mail(user_sudo.id, force_send=True)
                return self.web_login(*args, **kw)
            except UserError as e:
                qcontext['error'] = e.name or e.value
            except (SignupError, AssertionError) as e:
                if request.env["res.users"].sudo().search([("login", "=", qcontext.get("login"))]):
                    qcontext["error"] = _("Another user is already registered using this email address.")

                if request.env["res.users"].sudo().search([("phone", "=", qcontext.get("phone"))]):
                     qcontext["error"] = _("Phone Number Already exist !")
                else:
                    _logger.error("%s", e)
                    qcontext['error'] = _("Could not create a new account.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `values` from

```py
values = {key: qcontext.get(key) for key in ('db','login', 'name', 'password', 'phone')}
```

for a user creation then you get a problem with the key `db`. There is no field with name `db` on that model.

Comment: Yes, that what I got 
Any tips for checking is phone number already exist or not

Comment: I add this to check  `if request.env["res.users"].sudo().search([("phone", "=", qcontext.get("phone"))]): qcontext["error"] = _("Another user is already registered using this phone number.") `  but it not working until  the email given wrong else not
<br/>
case 1: Email exist  phone exist ==>` Another user is already registered using this phone number ` 
case 2 : Email exist Phone not exist ==>  `Another user is already registered using this email address. `
case 3 : Email not exist Phone not exist ==> Nothing happen (no phone number verification)